# How to subquery or combine some queries on SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

I'm looking to create a Query on SPARQL to find all alerts which the creation date is superior to the alert whose identified by _messageid = "58002774-4fea-11e4-BDAC" (i Don't know its creation date).

I tested queries below and work fine :

#### Query 1 : Display all the alerts and their creation date :

```
SELECT ?a ?ct
WHERE {
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?cts :Text ?ct.
}
```

#### Query 2 : Display the creation date of the alert that is identified by _messageid = "58002774-4fea-11e4-BDAC":

```
SELECT ?a ?ct
WHERE {
  ?a :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac".
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?cts :Text ?ct.
}
```

#### Query 3 : Display all alertes having creation date superior to the date "2014-10-09T15:15:00":

```
SELECT ?a ?ct
WHERE {
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?cts :Text ?ct.
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?ct) > xsd:dateTime("2014-10-09T15:15:00") ).
}
```

the problem is that i don't knew how to combine them to resolve my problem (**find all alerts which the creation date is superior to the alert whose identified by _messageid = "58002774-4fea-11e4-BDAC"**)

I tested some request (described below) by they don't work :

#### Query 4 :

```
SELECT ?a ?ct
WHERE {
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?cts :Text ?ct.
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?ct) > {SELECT ?ct2 WHERE { ?a2 :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac". ?a2 :CreateTimeSlot ?cts2. ?cts2 :Text ?ct2 } } )
}
```

#### Query 5 :

```
SELECT ?a ?ct
WHERE {
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?cts :Text ?ct.
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?ct) > xsd:dateTime({SELECT ?ct2 WHERE { ?a2 :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac". ?a2 :CreateTimeSlot ?cts2. ?cts2 :Text ?ct2 } }) )
}
```

#### Query 6 :

```
SELECT ?a
WHERE
{
  {
    SELECT ?a ?ct1
    WHERE
    {
      ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
      ?cts :Text ?ct1.
    }
    GROUP BY ?a 
  }.
  {
    SELECT ?a ?ct2
    WHERE
    {
      ?a :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac".
      ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
      ?cts :Text ?ct2.
    }
    GROUP BY ?a
  }.
  FILTER (xsd:dateTime(?ct1) > xsd:dateTime(?ct2)). 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the queries that work, and the attempts that did not work.  I'd suggest that for the future, though, you take a look at the [Mardown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

It sounds like you want to retrieve the creation date for the element with the specified messageId, and then get all the elements with a later creation date.  That's just this:

```
SELECT ?a ?cts ?dc
WHERE {
  ?x :CreateTimeSlot ?y.
  ?y :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac".
  ?y :Text ?xdate.

  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?cts :Text ?dc.
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?dc) > xsd:dateTime(?xdate) ).
}
```

That can be be cleaned up a bit with some blank nodes:

```
SELECT ?a ?cts ?dc
WHERE {
  [] :CreateTimeSlot [ :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac" ;
                       :Text ?xdate ] .

  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?cts :Text ?dc.
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?dc) > xsd:dateTime(?xdate) ).
}
```

and if you don't need the **?cts**, you can simplify as before with:

```
SELECT ?a ?cts ?dc
WHERE {
  [] :CreateTimeSlot [ :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac" ;
                       :Text ?xdate ] .

  ?a :CreateTimeSlot/:Text ?dc.
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?dc) > xsd:dateTime(?xdate) ).
}
```

### Original

If I understand what you're trying to do, it's just this:

```
SELECT ?a ?cts ?dc
WHERE {
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts.
  ?a :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac".
  ?cts :Text ?dc.
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?dc) > xsd:dateTime("2014-10-09T15:15:00") ).
}
```

There was a little bit of confusion about whether the value of the text property was going to be called **?dc** or **?ct**, so I went with **?dc**.

There are actually a few ways to clean this up, though.  This is just a matter of style, but I'd probably write this as (note the `;` syntax to select multiple properties on **?a** and the **xsd:dateTime** literal in the comparison):

```
SELECT ?a ?cts ?dc
WHERE {
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot ?cts ; 
     :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac".
  ?cts :Text ?dc
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?dc) > "2014-10-09T15:15:00"^^xsd:dateTime )
}
```

If you don't actually need the **?cts** value, you can simplify this even more:

```
SELECT ?a ?cts ?dc
WHERE {
  ?a :CreateTimeSlot/:Text ?dc ;
     :_messageid "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac".
  FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?dc) > "2014-10-09T15:15:00"^^xsd:dateTime )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help Joshua, but the problem is that i don't knew the creation date of the alert that the _messageid is "58002774-4fea-11e4-bdac", so i can't use your first code. then for your question about ?dc and ?ct they represent the same thing, i have just change the name of the variable.

Comment: @azedra What do you actually want to get in the final query?  It doesn't make sense to both "Display all the alerts and their creation date" and "Display the creation date of the alert that is identified by _messageid = "58002774-4fea-11e4-BDAC"".  What is it you actually want?  To show all the entries with a creation date after the creation date for the one with "58002774-4fea-11e4-BDAC"?